# regex ip address in format of 192[.]168[.]1[.]1

Tags: python, regex, ip-address

I got a task to match ip address in an article ,and some of these ip addresses in this article are in the format of

```
192.168.1.1
```

and others are like

```
192[.]168[.]1[.]2
```

I can match the former using the

```
ip_result = re.findall(r"(\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b)",string)
```

but i don't know how to match the ip address in such 192[.]168[.]1[.]2 format
Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Add `(?:\[\.\]|\.)` instead of `\.`

Comment: Why would anyone _want_ to use a regex to match 1-255? Why not just match digits and catch invalid values after converting, or just `split('.')` without a regex at all, or, best of all, just `ipaddress.ip_address`?

Comment: @S.Jovan thanks for your help ,the regex works

Comment: @abarnert nice idea ,thank you !

Comment: Be aware that regex will match 192.168[.]1.2